# Accessing the multiple selection UIView when tableview.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing=YES

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection, multipleselection

I iOS 5 Apple added functionality to make it easier to make a multiple selection table view through:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

When the table is in edit mode I can see the multiple selection mark but when I check it, it does not display the usual red checkmark to denote it is selected. So I assume I have to programatically access that UIView and set the appropriate image.

So my question is, how can I access the UIView that displays the circle that represents if the cell is selected or not?

[image: Mutiple selection table view]
<sub>(source: [winddisk.com](http://www.winddisk.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mail_multrow_select.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to programatically access the UIView and update it with the checkmark.

The solution to the problem was way easier, here it is:

[Cells not getting selected in UITableView with allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing set in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708186/cells-not-getting-selected-in-uitableview-with-allowsmultipleselectionduringedit)